# Split letters and assigning class

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having problems with the following, I need to separate each character in a span and assign a class depending on the character with javascript.

I have this:

```
<div>1111222</div>
```

and the final result should be this:

```
<div>
   <span class="e1">1</class>
   <span class="e1">1</class>
   <span class="e1">1</class>
   <span class="e1">1</class>
   <span class="e2">2</class>
   <span class="e2">2</class>
   <span class="e2">2</class>
</div>
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
var str = $('.test').text();
var result = "";
str = str.split("");
var h = $(this).text();
$.each(str,function(){
if( h = 1)
{
    result += '<span class="e1">' + this + '</span>';
}
else if ( h = 2)
{
    result += '<span class="e2">' + this + '</span>';
}
});
$('.test').html($(result));
```

Thanks

Comment: How do I assign a class depending on the actual character??? If it's 1 then class="e1" for example

Comment: You might start with valid markup, presumably `</class>` should be `</span>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var spanVals = $('div').text().split('');
for(var i = 0; i < spanVals.length; i++) {
    var span = $('<span>').addClass('e'+spanVals[i]).text(spanVals[i]);
    $('div').append(span);
}
```

Comment: What if I wanted to add a class to all the 1s and a different one to the 2s??

Comment: This does that too: `addClass('e'+spanVals[i])`

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have a reference to the div, then the following should do the job:

```
var div = document.getElementById('d0'); // id of div

// Get the text
var text = div.textContent;

// Clear the div content
div.innerHTML = '';

// Insert spans around characters
text.split('').forEach(function(c){
  var node = document.createElement('span').appendChild(document.createTextNode(c)).parentNode;
  node.className = 'e' + c;
  div.appendChild(node);
});
```

You will need a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill) for *forEach* for older browsers like IE 8.